# Write complex number in standard form. 5 cis 210 degrees

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Write complex number in standard form. 
5 cis 210 degrees.

Need help on this i tried and got the wrong answer resulting in -5 root 3/2+ 5i/2

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. In what quadrant is $210^{\circ}$ located in the unit circle?  How would that affect the signs in $\cos$ and $\sin$?
2. Is there a reference angle for $210^{\circ}$?  If so, can you use those angles to your advantage?